# Prediction results remain the same when input is fed to the estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I was trying to predict the classes of 28000 MNIST pictures, but `list(predict_results)` remains the same regardless of the changes in `input_fn`.

Here is the code for the prediction process:

```
mnist_classifier =  tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn = cnn_model_fn, model_dir = "/tmp/mnist_kaggle_model2")
for i in range(1,28000):
    input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(
        x = {'x': test_images[(i-1), ]},
        num_epochs = 1,
        shuffle = False
        )
    predict_results = mnist_classifier.predict(input_fn = input_fn)
    print(list(predict_results))
```

Here is how I reshaped `test_images`:

```
test_images = test_data.reshape(28000 , 28, 28, 1)
```

Is the problem with the way I reshaped `test_images`, or is it with `input_fn`?

===========================================================================

I am utterly confused with the problem and any help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: The code you post here is not properly indented, especially is this line inside or outside the for loop `predict_results = mnist_classifier.predict(input_fn = input_fn)`?

Comment: @neurite Sorry for the inconvenience, I will correct that typo right away.